# How to write this SQL statement correctly?

Tags: sql, join, informix

As written in the title: How to write this SQL statement correctly?

```
   select 
    sl.switch_ip,
    sl.switch_name, 
    count(m.switch_ip) as macentries,
    (select arpentries from (select sl1.switch_ip, sl1.switch_name, count(ar.switch_ip) as arpentries 
        from my_switchlist sl1 
        left Join my_arptable ar on ar.switch_ip = sl1.switch_ip
        group by sl1.switch_ip,sl1.switch_name 
        order by sl1.switch_ip))
    from my_switchlist sl 
        left Join my_mactable m on m.switch_ip = sl.switch_ip
    group by sl.switch_ip,sl.switch_name 
    order by sl.switch_ip
```

The select and the sub-select work fine if they are executed separately.
But as soon as I put them together I get the following error:

```
Error: A subquery has returned not exactly one row.
SQLState: 21000
ErrorCode: -284
Position: 470
```

Comment: Simple, your sub-select returns more than one row, and since you've tried to mash them into one select statement, it's assuming that only one row should be returned by the sub-query. Try joining the two select statements together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you want both the 'count' aggregates, which should be possible with something like this:

```
select
   macquery.switch_ip,
   macquery.switch_name,
   macquery.macentries,
   arpquery.arpentries
from
(
   select 
      sl.switch_ip as switch_ip,
      sl.switch_name as switch_name,  
      count(m.switch_ip) as macentries
   from my_switchlist sl 
   left outer join my_mactable m
   on m.switch_ip = sl.switch_ip
   group by
      sl.switch_ip,
      sl.switch_name 
) macquery

join

(
   select
      sl1.switch_ip as switch_ip,
      sl1.switch_name as switch_name,
      count(ar.switch_ip) as arpentries 
   from my_switchlist sl1 
   left outer join my_arptable ar
   on ar.switch_ip = sl1.switch_ip
   group by
      sl1.switch_ip,
      sl1.switch_name 
) arpquery

on  (macquery.switch_ip =  arpquery.switch_ip
    and  macquery.switch_name =  arpquery.switch_name)
```

Comment: Here I get a syntax error (Probably caused by SQuirreL or Informix). I get the idea though.

Comment: Oh, I see. I didn't actually test this out, so there could be something that crept in - what exactly is the syntax error?

Comment: How does the join work by columns (switch_ip, switch_name) or does it do it on row numbers?

Comment: Error: A syntax error has occurred.
SQLState:  42000
ErrorCode: -201
Position: 681

Comment: So the principle here is that each subquery returns what essentially looks like a table that has 3 columns: 'switch_ip', 'switch_name' and a 'count' ('macentries' in the first, and 'arpentries' in the second). The outermost query and join simply exploit this to join the two 'tables' together on the 'keys' of 'switch_ip' and 'switch_name'

Comment: On the syntax front, I'm not sure - I tried to make it ANSI compliant, but maybe try changing the 'left outer join's to 'left join' and possibly killing off some of the extra line breaks/whitespace

Comment: OK Cool. That should help to solve the problem. I'll accept your answer after I solved the problem. Thx

Comment: Sry for my dumb question - didn't see the last two lines XD

Answer (score 0):

Probably there are more than one "sl1.switch_ip,sl1.switch_name" groups in your "my_switchlist, my_arptable" join.

```
select arpentries from (select sl1.switch_ip, sl1.switch_name, count(ar.switch_ip) as arpentries 
        from my_switchlist sl1 
        left Join my_arptable ar on ar.switch_ip = sl1.switch_ip
        group by sl1.switch_ip,sl1.switch_name 
        order by sl1.switch_ip)
```

The above query should not return more than one result in order you to use its result in your outer query. So probably there is more than one "sl1.switch_ip,sl1.switch_name" group.

Comment: How can there be more than one column? As I said: the query runs fine if run separately - returning one column

Comment: If you inner query returns more than one result, you cannot use its result in your aggregate query.